Has anyone used Critic2 with Quantum ESPRESSO? Need help to determine non-nuclear charge determination
I have installed Critic2. Need to know how to determine interstitial site locations of a structure and their charges in those sites (in non nuclear maxima sites). I have calculated 3D charge densities of some materials using Quantum ESPRESSO.
Any simple example suggestion (input files, output files, etc) would be greatly appreciated.

From the Quick Start Guide at Critic2 site:

Critic2 reads the user commands from a single input file (the .cri
file). A simple input is:

crystal cubicBN.cube
load cubicBN.cube
yt


which reads the crystal structure from a cube file (cubicBN.cube),
then the electron density from the same cube file, and then calculates
the atomic charges and volumes using the YT method. Critic2 accepts
many structure and density/scalar field formats written by quantum
chemistry software (see the manual for more info).
To run critic2, do:

critic2 cubicBN.cri

The full list of keywords that you can use for each of the task Critic2 is capable to run are here.
For example, the keyword POINT:
POINT [x.r y.r z.r|file.s] [ALL] [FIELD {id.s|"expr.s"}]

will allow you to

Calculate the value of the reference field or an arithmetic expression
at point (x.r, y.r, z.r) in crystallographic coordinates (if the
structure is a CRYSTAL) or molecular Cartesian coordinates (if a
MOLECULE).


Thanks @Camps for the information. Could you please suggest how we can determine interstitial (or non nuclear maxima) site locations and charge at those points?
